# Why `sort()` need `T` to be `Ord`?

Tags: rust

https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/slice.rs.html#268-270

https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cmp.rs.html#1034

```rust
pub fn sort(&mut self)
where
    T: Ord,
{
    merge_sort(self, |a, b| a.lt(b));
}

fn lt(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool {
    matches!(self.partial_cmp(other), Some(Less))
}
```

It uses `lt()` inside the `merge_sort()`. If `partial_cmp()` returns `None` then `lt()` returns `Less`.

So, it seems like `PartialOrd` is enough for `sort()`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if `partial_cmp(a, b)` is None, then so is `partial_cmp(b, a)`. You can't define both `a<b` and  `b<a`. You can extend a partial order to a total order (using for example, topological sort), but there's no simple standard way to apply standard fast sorting algorithms to partial orders.

Comment: `sort` can't sort if there are values that are incomparable. Using `Ord` is a logical constraint, not a technical constraint.

Comment: As a more specific example, using `partial_cmp` with floats where one of the values is `f64::NAN` will return `None` no matter which direction you compare in, so `f64::NAN` is both "greater" *and* "less" than whatever you compare it to. This obviously breaks your sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both historical and logical reasons.

Back in the days, before `impl<T> [T]`, [`sort` first used `cmp()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/ee9921aaedb26de3cac4c1c174888528f68bbd3f/src/libcollections/slice.rs#L606-L607) instead of `lt()`. That changed [about 5 years ago](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/39538) for optimization reasons. At that point, the constraint could have been changed from `Ord` to `PartialOrd`. And truly, it sparked [another discussion about `PartialOrd` and `Ord`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41270).

However, there's a logical reason too: for any two indices `i` and `j` within `[0..values.len()]` and `i <= j`, you expect the following to hold if `values` has been sorted:

```
assert!(values[i] <= values[j]);
```

Note that I said *any* indices where `i <= j`. However, with `PartialOrd`, we can have some value `x` that's uncompareable to any other value, for example `f64::NAN`. It's completely unclear where `x` should be sorted in this case, as **both** `f64::NAN < y` and `y < f64::NAN` yield `false` for *any* `y`, and your expectations have been mislead and your day ruined. To really sort all values, we need all of them to be compareable to the whole domain. But that's exactly `Ord`.

Now, an implementation could place all incomparable values at the end of the collection, but that would be an arbitrary decision which might yield surprising results. But instead of using some seemingly random approach in `sort`, the Rust standard library provides [`sort_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by) to enable *you* to decide:

```
values.sort_by(|a, b| a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap());
```

This is now an explicit choice. And as the [Python Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says: *"Explicit is better than implicit."*

Comment: According to the docs you link to, you can only use `partial_cmp` like that with floats if you know that your slice doesn't contain `NaN`, so it's still not sorting any incomparable values.

Comment: @Herohtar Right. The moment you try to sort any incomparable values, you (might) get a panic.

Comment: This is only an issue because `Ord` does not/can not implement a total order for floats, all caused by it's poorly designed hiearchy between `Ord` and `PartialOrd`.